# How to apply filter function on 2D array/list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find only positive numbers from 2D list
list1 = [[-1,2,3,4,-2], [-4,3,2]]

> output = [[2,3,4],[3,2]]

I tried  so far `print(list(filter(lambda x: (x>0), [[-1,2,3,4,-2], [-4,3,2]]) ))`
but I'm having trouble applying 2D list in filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not readable but just to answer your question use `map` above `filter`

**Ex:**

```
list1 = [[-1,2,3,4,-2], [-4,3,2]]
print(list(map(lambda x:list(filter(lambda y: (y>0), x)), list1)))

# Better to use nested list comprehension 
print([[j for j in i if j >0] for i in list1])
```

**Output:**

```
[[2, 3, 4], [3, 2]]
```

Comment: Please tell me how to square this output in the same map function. @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

That way won't work because in "lambda x: (x>0)" x is a list and not a number. To make it work you need to map the 2D list and filter each element/sublist.

```
list1 = [[-1,2,3,4,-2], [-4,3,2]]

output = list(
    map(
       lambda l: list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, l)),
       list1
    )
)

print(output)
```

This is the code executed giving the right result:
https://ideone.com/gN5Xct